# r cumsum-like function for splitting dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

Given the following dataframe:

```
mydf <- data.frame(x=c(1:10,10:1),y=c(10:1,1:10))
```

How is it possible to `split` it such that each sub-dataframe will have consecutive values of one column which are greater than the other column?

For example in `mydf`, the outcome that I am hoping for is `split`ing it into three dataframes:

1. (y > x; should contain the first 5 rows of `mydf`)
2. (x > y; should contain rows 6 to 15 of `mydf`)
3. (y > x again; should contain the last 5 rows of `mydf`)

I tried using the following code but it produced bad results where each y > x would be split individually; moreover, dataframes where x > y would contain a y > x in the first row:

```
split(mydf, cumsum(mydf$x > mydf$y))
```

Another less elegant approach I tried to do is `sapply` with individual `if`s inside the `split` function, but I don't want to go this path because of performance issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
rl <- with(mydf, rle(x >y))
grp <- inverse.rle(within.list(rl , values <- seq_along(values)))
split(mydf, grp)  
#$`1`
#  x  y
#1 1 10
#2 2  9
#3 3  8
#4 4  7
#5 5  6

#$`2`
#    x y
#6   6 5
#7   7 4
#8   8 3
#9   9 2
#10 10 1
#11 10 1
#12  9 2
#13  8 3
#14  7 4
#15  6 5

#$`3`
#   x  y
#16 5  6
#17 4  7
#18 3  8
#19 2  9
#20 1 10
```

Or

```
group <-  with(mydf, cumsum(c(1,abs(diff(x >y)))))
split(mydf, group)
```

Or you can use `rleid` from the devel version of `data.table` (from @David Arenburg's comments) , i.e. `v1.9.5`.  Onstructions to install it are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

```
 library(data.table)
 split(mydf, rleid(with(mydf, y > x)))
```

Comment: Or maybe simpler `library(data.table) ; split(mydf, rleid(with(mydf, y > x)))`

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks, do you want to post it as separate

Comment: I think `rleid()` is only in the development version of `data.table`.

Comment: Note: `rleid` only exists in the development version of `data.table` (i.e. 1.9.5). Not in the current CRAN version (i.e. 1.9.4).

Comment: you can do it more compact : `split(mydf, with(rle(with(mydf,x<y)), rep(seq_along(values), lengths)))`